Don't quite know how to fill the table of transporting frames
I'm learning computer network and I encountered a question in my process of doing exercise. Actually I know what's the path of transporting the frames(source/destination MAC address, source/destination IP address) but I'm confused with how to fill the type.
I have drawn the path of transporting the frames and I wonder how to fill the type of the table.
